# How to copy a value from one field to other if a field exists by using ingestnode pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I want to create a new field called kubernetes.pod.name if fields called prometheus.labels.pod exists in the logs. I found out that from the set processor I could copy the value which is present in prometheus.labels.pod to a new field kubernetes.pod.name but I need to do this conditionally as the pod name keeps on changing.

How do i set a condition such that if field prometheus.labels.pod exists then only I need to add a new field called kubernetes.pod.name (both has the same value)

```
ctx.prometheus?.labels?.namespace== "name_of_namespace"
```

could be do similarly can we do

```
ctx.prometheus?.labels?.pod== "*"
```

to check if this field exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text is a string and if its required to set a condition that if it exists then best way is to use the below condition in set processor.

```
ctx.prometheus?.labels?.namespace!=null
```

This is how I implemented the above scenario by using ingest node pipeline.

```
"set": {
  "field": "kubernetes.pod.name",
  "copy_from": "prometheus.labels.pod",
  "if": "ctx.prometheus?.labels?.pod!=null",
  "ignore_failure": true
}
```

Comment: Also note that `copy_from` is only supported from ES 7.11 onwards.

Comment: Agree with this. I am using the latest version.

Comment: You can also add `"override": false` to be sure not to over write field.